# Integrate a Prestashop in an existing website. (separated servers)

Tags: web-services, iframe, web, prestashop

I would like to add an online shop (administered by prestashop) to my existing website. The shop is provided and managed by an external provider (so it cannot be on the same server than the website).

What would be a good solution to integrate the shop into my webapp?

I see 3 possibilites :

- I use the prestashop as an iframe in a page of my website (maybe there is some services or mods available to do it in a cleaner way)
- I use a custom style to make the prestashop look like it is a part of the website (however i am not very fond of making my users leave my domain)
- I use the prestashop webservices (The documentation is a bit messy, I dont even now if it is possible to add something to cart via WS)

Answer (score 1):

Use a "cname" (canonical name) dns record redirecting a subdomain to the other domain. I.E. Create a cname with shop.domain.tld and as value set the url of the shop provider. Remember to configure your shop with target url shop.domain.tld

Comment: I am going to try that. I let you know of the result!

Answer (score 1):

> I use the prestashop as an iframe in a page of my website (maybe there is some services or mods available to do it in a cleaner way)

1. iframes are generally considered ad very bad user experience. For
   example, you will not be able to get a direct link to a specific
   product...

> I use a custom style to make the prestashop look like it is a part of the website (however i am not very fond of making my users leave my domain)

2. You can design a theme that reflect the look&feel of your website, and create a subdomain for your shop. This is a common pattern, and users will not leave your domain. **This is the solution I would go for**.

> I use the prestashop webservices (The documentation is a bit messy, I dont even now if it is possible to add something to cart via WS)

3. I don't think Webservices are designed for that kind of use.